GeoNetwork : Change label of the status of data (record preview)
In order to edit the label for the status of data (for instance : from "Finalised" toward "Data set finalised"), I succeed in editing the codelists.xml ISO 19115-3. So, indeed, after a tomcat9 restart, we can see the change within the edit form.
However, the change is not taken into account for the preview label. How to extend the change at the preview interface?

